# How to return data in json format its returns string

Tags: c#, json, winforms, json.net

I have following code but its return data in string type.. how to return data in json format.

```
[HttpGet]
        public string Save(BookingInformation BookingJson)
        {
    SuccessResponse msg = new SuccessResponse();
    msg.FleetBookingId = objMaster.Current.Id.ToString();
    msg.Success = true;
    msg.Message = "Booking saved successfully";
    var obj = serializer.Serialize(msg).Trim('"');
    return obj;
}
```

Calling Method

```
public async void getsave(BookingInformation BookingJson)
{
    var baseAddress = new Uri("http://mycar.com");

    string url = "/api/Jobs/SaveBooking";

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
    {
        var Jsonlines = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(BookingJson);
        //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept-charset", "utf-8");

        //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("authorization", "Basic *sample_token*");

        using (var content = new StringContent(Jsonlines, System.Text.Encoding.Default, "application/json"))
        {
            using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content))
            {
                object responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Result is : how to return only json. I want return data in json format

```
"{\"FleetBookingId\":\"36572\",\"Success\":true,\"Message\":\"Booking saved successfully\"}"
```

i want like this :

```
{"FleetBookingId":"36572","Success":true,"Message":"Booking saved successfully"}
```

Comment: Then don't return a `string` from your API method, but a `SuccessResponse` and let the API's serializer do its work automagically.

Comment: how to return data in json format because i am using this service many languages.. python android and php..

Comment: What part of my previous comment didn't you understand?

Comment: its return  string format i want json format.. simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't return a string from your API method, but a `SuccessResponse` and let the API's serializer do its work:

```
[HttpGet]
public SuccessResponse Save(BookingInformation BookingJson)
{
    SuccessResponse msg = new SuccessResponse();
    msg.FleetBookingId = objMaster.Current.Id.ToString();
    msg.Success = true;
    msg.Message = "Booking saved successfully";

    return msg;
}
```

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks for improvements in answer :-) Now is better.

Answer (score 0):

Return A Json Result from Controller

```
    public ActionResult GetSuggestionFirst()
    {
        var search = Request.Params["term"].Trim();

        var itemList = (from items in db.TblProductSuggestionFirsts where items.Name.StartsWith(search) select new { label = items.Name, value = items.Name }).Take(50).ToList();

        return Json(itemList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This return json object (Json look like string, just parse it in Javascript)

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer thanks :)

```
var content = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(msg);

JToken json = JObject.Parse(content);
```

Comment: It makes no sense to do a JSON roundtrip within your controller method. You have `msg` right there. What are you going to do with the `JToken json`?

Comment: @CodeCoster finally OP did the same thing

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster your support but i really want json data its working fine for me

Comment: @sumngh no, this is in the controller, not on the client side.